# Alternative way to list all part tables that have existing entries/tuples

Tags: datajoint

I have one single master Subject table which have several part tables.  One convenient thing about Table.delete() is that is displays a prompt with all existing entries that were created under that Subject.  Aside from delete() is there an alternative way to print what part table entries were created under a single Subject entry?

Thank you

Comment: Still thinking through the best answer here, but it may involve `subject.Subject.descendants()`, which will give you the backend name convention for all tables related to the one you've picked. Maybe theres a way to go from that list to the set of entries you're interested in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a slow process, but I think I would do the following to see where entries were:

```py
(subject.Subject & 'subject="<NAME>"').descendants(as_objects=True)
```

Not sure if you'd be better off with `children` (1 level down) or `descendants` (all the way down). `delete` gives the full set of descendants, using `table.delete_quick(get_count=True)`.

EDIT:
To just get the counts, you might want:

```py
[print(i.table_name,len(i)) for i in (subject.Subject & 'subject="<NAME>"').descendants(as_objects=True)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the entry count of all the part tables restricted by some restriction (e.g. `subject_name`), you can do something like this:

```
restriction = {'subject_name': 'my_star_subject'}

for part_table in Subject.parts(as_objects=True):
    part_table_query = part_table & restriction
    print(f'{part_table.table_name}: len(part_table_query)')
```